# How to get all the docs by id-s, which are stored in another schema's subdocument using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two schemas. The first one looks like this:

```
Entity1 = new Schema ({ 
    field1: String, 
    field2: String 
});
```

And the second one looks like this:

```
childSchema = new Schema({
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    entity1id: Schema.Types.ObjectId //Entity1_ID
});

Entity2 = new Schema ({ 
    fieldA : String, 
    fieldB : String, 
    child  : [childSchema] 
});
```

`childSchema` contains `Entity1._id`s. I want to get all the Entity1 docs, `id`s of which are stored in the `Entity2.childSchema`.

I mean... If `Entity2.child` contains docs

`{ field1 : "", field2 : "", entity1id : "id_03" }, 
 { field1 : "", field2 : "", entity1id : "id_14" }`

I would like to find `Entity1` docs with `"id_03"` and `"id_14"`. I tried to use a `forEach/findOne`, tried some weird queries with `"$in"` or something like that, but got nothing. 
Is there any  way to do this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you show what all you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use populate and get the `entity1` documents with `entity2` documents itself. This way you wont need to do `forEach` for all the `child` and `findOne` for `entity1` document.

**Try this:**

```
Entity2.find({_id :entity2Id})
   .populate({path : 'child.entity1id' , model : 'Entity1'})
   .exec(function(err,result){
        //result will have all the docs with Entity1 document populated inside each doc
        //use it however you want.
});
```

you can put `find` criteria anything you may find suitable. I used `_id : entity2Id` as an exaample.

For more information on `Populate`, Please read [Mongoose Populate Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: That's it! The magic itself. Thank u a lot! It works just as needed.